# Select joined information from multiple tables return too much

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am trying to select data from three tables using `JOIN` but I get too many rows. What I have (simplified) is:

```
table_relations (id1, id2) 
table1_names (id1, name1) and 
table2_names (id2, name2, group).
```

`table_relations` contain unique combinations of `id1 and id2`
`table1_names` contain a unique set of `id1 and name1`.
But `table2_names` contains many duplicate rows of `id2, name2 and group`.

`table_relations` is the main table.
I want to select id1, id2, name1, name2 where group = 1 without getting duplicate rows.
I have tried:

```
SELECT t2.name2, tr.id1, tr.id2, t1.name1 
FROM table_relations tr
JOIN table2 t2 ON tr.id2 = t2.id2
JOIN table1 t1 ON tr.id1 = t1.id1
WHERE t2.group = 1
```

I get all the rows from table t2. How to avoid this?

Comment: You say id1 + id2 is unique in table_relations. And of course id1 should be unique in table1_names and id2 should be unique in table2_names. You join all these tables and restrict your results to only those rows where table2_names.group = 1. There can be no duplicates in the result, if your tables are set up properly. If you get all rows from this table, then all records have group = 1. If you still think you don't get a proper result, then please show us sample data, the result you get and the result you want instead.

Comment: Oh, you are describing tables table2_names and table2_names, but you are selecting from table1 and table2. I guess that's a mere typo in the description or query? Or are you really using the wrong tables?

Answer (score 1):

This should take care of your double rows. I am not 100% sure of yoru exact data model though...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.name2, tr.id1, tr.id2, t1.name1 
  FROM table_relations tr
  JOIN table2 t2 ON tr.id2 = t2.id2
  JOIN table1 t1 ON tr.id1 = t1.id1
 WHERE t2.group = 1
```

If this is not what you need, please specify desired output and what yuo get so far :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for fast response. DISTINCT seems to solve my problem. GROUP BY above filtered out too much. I have the situation that table_relations could have more instances of id2 and here name2 only was returned once if using GROUP BY. Not quite sure why it works for DISTINCT...

Comment: @user3008614: If you get a smaller result set with `DISTINCT`, then there is a problem with your tables. Either id1 + id2 are not unique in table_ralations or id1 is not unique in table1 or id2 is not unique in table2. Check this, delete duplicates, add unique constraints on your tables (e.g. primary keys). Using `DISTINCT` is most often an indicator for a badly written query, but here it is obviously indicating data consistency problems.

Answer (score -2):

You can add

```
GROUP BY t2.id2
```

Then you should get only one row for each id2 in table2.

Comment: And hopefully a series of error messages for the other fields that you dont; group on and which are not in aggregate functions ;)

Comment: Yeah, not a great answer.